# Ipod/Iphone/Ipad cable hack

Tags: usb, data, iphone

Has anyone hacked an IOS cable and knows what data is going in and out of which wire. Maybe a diagram of an iphone cut cable?

Comment: Yes, someone has hacked it and made diagrams of the pinouts.  Do you have a more specific question?  Which data do you want to access?

Comment: ^ that website does not work

Comment: and where can i find the diagrams because i have not seen any and i have been looking

Comment: http://ipl.derpapst.eu/wiki/Dock_Connector

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Pinouts.ru](http://pinouts.ru/PortableDevices/ipod_pinout.shtml) has a great description of the connector.

The [iPodLinux wiki](http://ipl.derpapst.eu/wiki/Apple_Accessory_Protocol) has a great page describing the serial protocol.

Here is the connector diagram (with the blank side of the connector facing up):

[image]

Pins 12 and 13 are Tx and Rx, respectively. Rx and Tx are TTL level. Pin 1 is GND, and pin 21 is serial enable. To enable the serial port, tie a 6.8 kΩ resistor to GND.

Comment: @GeorgeH, can you please bring over the information from your post and explain here. Links die, but Stack exchange never will.

Comment: Sorry - I tried, but the pinouts.ru page has a pretty in depth table that I couldn't figure out how to bring over.

Comment: @GeorgeH, Just sharing that a good source often dies but SE keeps it data available for download regularly. If the link dies your answer does not have any substance.

Comment: is there a diagram (picture) of which wires send which signal?
thats what im asking

Comment: I edited my answer to add an image of the connector